# Why PWA App launched from "Add to Homescreen" can't load without Internet connection?

Tags: google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, workbox

We have made our site (https://www.hijup.com) PWA ready with Add to HomeScreen capability. The app can be launched from the HomeScreen with Internet connection on. But when the connection is turned off, there is a dialog box as follow:

"To use [my_app_name] for the first time, please connect to the Internet"

Why does it still require Internet connection? All the JS & CSS are already precached (using `workbox.precaching`) and the `start_url` has been cached with `networkFirst` strategy. Moreover, it is not the first time I launched the app (as what the dialog message suggests).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is resolved by fixing the route matcher:

Previously it was:

```
 workbox.routing.registerRoute(new RegExp('www\\.hijup\\.com/id/$'), pagesHandler);
```

The Regex doesn't match my `start_url`: `"/en?utm_source=a2hs"`

The fix is to allow Regex to match suffix `?utm_source=a2hs`

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(new RegExp('www\\.hijup\\.com/id/?(?:\\?.+)?$'), pagesHandler);
```

Answer (score -1):

Good job in making your site PWA compliant...almost. There is one little thing left, causing this issue as per the Chrome Lighthouse PWA audit report. start_url is not valid in the manifest.json. 
Try putting

```
"start_url": "https://www.hijup.com/",
```

instead of

```
"start_url": "/en?utm_source=a2hs",
```

You can run Chrome dev tools > Audit -> Progressive web app for your self to see if the issue is getting fixed(it will when the start URL is correctly served)

Comment: After experimenting both options, I conclude that the `start_url` can be a relative path. My fix is in the answer below